# Android Studio. Пропала кнопка запуска приложения. Хотел проверить пути к Яве - окно Структура проекта не открывается.Как теперь запустить приложение?

Tags: android-studio

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В настройках тоже искал. Всё перетыкал там - ничего не помогает.

Comment: Попробуйте File->Invalidate Caches / Restart

Comment: Закрыть проект. Проводником виндовс удалить из папки проекта папки `.gradle`, `.idea`, файл `.gitignore`, в папке `app` удалить `build`, `release`,  `.gitignore`. Потом открыть проект.

Comment: После первого способа Студия вообще сбилась с толку: Сверху пишет, что Gradle синхронизирует проект, в то же время снизу пишет, что синхронизация завершена. А ещё, он теперь выделил красным очень много правильного кода, из-за того, что у меня якобы выставлен мин. уровень API 1. Но в файле build.gradle minSdk = 24. Что теперь делать?

Comment: ВЫ нашли решение????????????????????????????????????

Comment: Возможно у вас проблема с adb

Comment: Я нашёл решение давно. Потом пришёл апдейт для студии, и всё.

Answer (score 0):

Наблюдаю такое очень часто. Два самых простых решения:

#### 1. Собирать с подключением дебага - нажать на зелёного жучка (справа)

Как сайд эффект - могут срабатывать ненужные breakpoints. Для однократных сборок такой путь удобнее всего. Нужно просто привыкнуть, что иногда придётся нажимать не на Play, а на жучка...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

#### 2. Закрыть проект и открыть его снова

По сравнению с [инвалидацией кеша/gradle clean/gradle rebuild/перезагрузкой ПК] - самый быстрый способ. После закрытия проекта автоматически откроется окошко со списком проектов, в котором просто нужно будет выбрать требуемый. Если закрыть Android Studio - придётся его открывать заново, а если закрыть лишь проект - не придётся ждать пока Android Studio выгрузится/загрузится

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]